# s3cmd invalidation choose distribution

Tags: amazon-s3, s3cmd, invalidation

I am trying to use s3cmd tool to invalidate my files,
it  seems s3cmd automatically choose a distribution for me,
but I have more distributions from the same bucket,  how can I choose distribution to invalidate ?

I have tried this :

`s3cmd sync —cf-invalidate myfile cf://XXXXXXXXXX/mypath` 
but it does not work. I get this: 
       `Invalid source/destination”`

any idea?

thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you'd be looking to force an invalidation via the origin (i.e. your S3 bucket or similar) like so:

```
s3cmd --cf-invalidate _site/ s3://example-origin.com/
```

Comment: the local file should be prepared well.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my final conclusion:
after many many tries , the solution is very restrict.

1. follow this format:

`s3cmd sync --cf-invalidate --acl-public --preserve --recursive ./[local_folder] s3://[my_bucket]/[remote_folder]/`

2. when I run this command , the actual folder should be in command running folder
3. local file should have ./
4. remote folder should be end by /

Answer (score 0):

I could not make `s3cmd`'s invalidation work, so I used `s3cmd` to update the file and `cloudfront-invalidator` to do the invalidation. The script reads the aws authentication used by `s3cmd` for `cloudfront-invalidator`.

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ -z "$(which s3cmd)" ]; then
  echo "s3cmd is not installed or is not on the PATH"
  exit -1
fi

if [ -z "$(which cloudfront-invalidator)" ]; then
  echo "cloudfront-invalidator is not installed or is not on the PATH"
  echo "See https://github.com/reidiculous/cloudfront-invalidator"
  echo "TL;DR: sudo gem install cloudfront-invalidator"
  exit -1
fi

function awsKeyId {
  awk -F '=' '{if (! ($0 ~ /^;/) && $0 ~ /aws_access_key_id/) print $2}' ~/.aws/config | tr -d ' '
}

function awsSecret {
  awk -F '=' '{if (! ($0 ~ /^;/) && $0 ~ /aws_secret_access_key/) print $2}' ~/.aws/config | tr -d ' '
}

export file="stylesheets/main.css"
export distributionId=blahblah
export bucket=www.blahblah

s3cmd -P -m 'text/css' put public/$file s3://$bucket/$f
cloudfront-invalidator invalidate `awsKeyId` `awsSecret` $distributionId $file
```

Comment: actually  I created a sinatra server to sent post data which include full xml data to start invalidation instead.  my sh will just sent a string content key of files.
curl  -X GET "http://[sinatra_server_ip]:[port]/signinval?objectList=${filelist}&s3dist=${s3dist}&token=${serverToken}&bucket=${bucket}&type=${fileType}"